# Passing a port number to lsof in a shell function

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal, lsof

I wrote an alias in my bash profile to help me kill rogue rails server processes that don't cleanly close. This alias works well.

```
alias kill3000="lsof -i tcp: 3000 -t | xargs kill -9 | echo 'killed processes on port 3000'"
```

I wanted to make it more general purpose, for frameworks that work on other ports. I tried to make a similar function, so I could pass the port number as a variable, but I get an error. The function I wrote looks like this...

```
function killproc (){
    "lsof -i tcp:$1 -t | xargs kill -9 | echo 'killed processes on port $1'"
}
```

However, when I run "killproc 3000", I get the following error:

```
lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i tcp:
```

I'm struggling to understand the problem, I appreciate any help.

Comment: quoting the whole line `"lsof -i ... killed ..$'"` looks suspect. Also to debug the situation, learn to use `set -vx ; ... cmd .... ; set +vx` to see how the shell in interpreting your code. the lines beginning with `+` show all variable values in place. All `"` dbl-quoted strings are "normalized" to `'` single-quoted strings. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, `set -vx` was very helpful in finding the problem. The variable was repeating, so it was looking for port 3000 3000, which created the error. I'm not sure exactly why that was happening, but running `exec bash`  solved the problem for me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the double-quotes are involved.

Give a try to this:

```
function killproc (){
    lsof -i tcp:"$1" -t | xargs kill -9
    lsof -i tcp:"$1" -t 2>/dev/null >/dev/null || printf "killed processes on port %s\n" "$1"
}
```

The message is printed only if there is no more process found listening on the port pspecified.

If you get some troubles, follow @shellter instruction.
Run a test with `set -vx ; killproc 300 ; set +vx`and edit the question to add the output generated.

Comment: Thank you, your answer (and @shellter's comment) helped me figure it out. My variable was duplicating, so `3000` became `3000 3000`. Not sure why, but refreshing the environment with `exec bash` solved it. Your function works great.